# SkiaSharp - scale image down and reduce quality (and hence image size)

Tags: c#, image-processing, skiasharp

We are using .NET 7 and SkiaSharp 2.88.3. We have the following controller action which is used to retrieve a .jpg or .png image from disk and scale it according to `scaleFactor` parameter (`1.0` means original size, `0.5` means dividing both width and height by half).

```cs
public IActionResult LoadImage(string imageName, double scaleFactor = 1.0)
{
    if (imageName.IsNullOrEmpty())
    {
        return NotFound();
    }

    var imagePath = Path.Combine(_env.ContentRootPath, imageName);

    var extension = Path.GetExtension(imagePath);
    var contentType = MimeTypeMapping.GetMimeTypeFromExtension(extension);
    var img = System.IO.File.OpenRead(imagePath);

    var resizedImage = FileHelpers.ResizeImage(img, extension, scaleFactor);
    
    return File(resizedImage, contentType);
}
```

The implementation of `FileHelpers.ResizeImage` is the following:

```cs
public static Stream ResizeImage(Stream imgStream, string extension, double scaleFactor)
{
    if (scaleFactor <= 0.0)
    {
        throw new ArgumentException("Negative scale factor is not allowed", nameof(scaleFactor));
    }

    if (scaleFactor == 1.0)
    {
        return imgStream;
    }

    using (var skImage = SKBitmap.Decode(imgStream))
    {
        int newHeight = (int)(skImage.Height * scaleFactor);
        int newWidth = (int)(skImage.Width * scaleFactor);

        using (var scaledBitmap = skImage.Resize(new SKImageInfo(newWidth, newHeight), SKFilterQuality.Low))
        {
            using (var image = SKImage.FromBitmap(scaledBitmap))
            {
                using (var encodedImage = image.Encode(MimeTypeMapping.GetSkiaSharpImageFormatFromExtension(extension), 50))
                {
                    var stream = new MemoryStream();
                    encodedImage.SaveTo(stream);
                    stream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
                    return stream;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

We also have the following helper class which maps file extension to mime/SkiaSharp type:

```cs
public static class MimeTypeMapping
{
    public static string GetMimeTypeFromExtension(string extension)
    {
        if (extension.IsNullOrEmpty())
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(extension));
        }

        return _mimeTypeMapping.TryGetValue(extension, out string mimeType) ? mimeType : DEFAULT_MIME_TYPE;
    }

    public static SKEncodedImageFormat GetSkiaSharpImageFormatFromExtension(string extension)
    {
        if (extension.IsNullOrEmpty())
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(extension));
        }

        return _skiaSharpImageFormatMapping.TryGetValue(extension, out SKEncodedImageFormat imageFormat) ? imageFormat : DEFAULT_IMAGE_FORMAT;
    }

    private const string DEFAULT_MIME_TYPE = "application/octet-stream";
    private const SKEncodedImageFormat DEFAULT_IMAGE_FORMAT = SKEncodedImageFormat.Png;

    private static readonly Dictionary<string, string> _mimeTypeMapping = new(StringComparer.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase)
    {
        {".jpe", "image/jpeg"},
        {".jpeg", "image/jpeg"},
        {".jpg", "image/jpeg"},
        {".png", "image/png"}
    };

    private static readonly Dictionary<string, SKEncodedImageFormat> _skiaSharpImageFormatMapping = new(StringComparer.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase)
    {
        {".png", SKEncodedImageFormat.Png },
        {".jpg", SKEncodedImageFormat.Jpeg },
        {".jpeg", SKEncodedImageFormat.Jpeg },
        {".jpe", SKEncodedImageFormat.Jpeg }
    };
}
```

We performed some benchmarks of `FileHelpers.ResizeImage` method for 2 images (.jpg and .png), both of size 2MB. We obtained the following results with BenchmarkDotNet:

```
BenchmarkDotNet v0.13.7, Windows 10 (10.0.19045.3324/22H2/2022Update)
Intel Xeon CPU E5-1650 v2 3.50GHz, 1 CPU, 12 logical and 6 physical cores
.NET SDK 7.0.400
  [Host]     : .NET 7.0.10 (7.0.1023.36312), X64 RyuJIT AVX
  DefaultJob : .NET 7.0.10 (7.0.1023.36312), X64 RyuJIT AVX


      Method | ScaleFactor | FileName | Mean         |   Error     |  StdDev     |
------------ |------------ |--------- |-------------:|------------:|------------:|
 ResizeImage |         0.3 |  2mb.jpg | 186,894.4 μs | 3,693.47 μs | 5,177.73 μs |
 ResizeImage |         0.3 |  2mb.png | 156,329.1 μs | 2,013.53 μs | 1,883.45 μs |
 ResizeImage |         0.5 |  2mb.jpg | 239,835.7 μs | 4,319.17 μs | 8,321.57 μs |
 ResizeImage |         0.5 |  2mb.png | 347,502.4 μs | 2,455.75 μs | 2,050.67 μs |
 ResizeImage |           1 |  2mb.jpg |     645.3 μs |    12.57 μs |    12.34 μs |
 ResizeImage |           1 |  2mb.png |     648.8 μs |    12.59 μs |    14.99 μs |
```

Our users complain that they notice that image load times are slow, especially for larger images. Is there anything that we can do to improve the performance of `FileHelpers.ResizeImage` method (we are fine with reducing image quality for the sake of speed)? Can we decrease quality of png images as well? Our application is deployed inside Linux Docker container. Benchmarks were performed on the Windows 10 machine.

Comment: Your code looks correct. I guess if you need it to be faster, you'll have to dig into SkiaSharp itself.

Comment: @PMF What do you mean by digging into SkiaSharp? Forking their repository and modifying its source code?

Comment: Yes, that's what I meant. They would certainly appeciate a patch improving performance. If your limit the values of your scale factor to even divisors (0.5, 0.25, etc) then you could also write a very fast, but simple algorithm.

Comment: How big are the images that have been complained about? Here we see worst one with about 350ms, so I'd say resizing does not seem to be your bottleneck. Without knowing the surrounding numbers of course. Have you also considered caching/persisting the downsized images?

Comment: "image load times are slow, especially for larger images" - what does this have to do with resizing.

Comment: @NickKovalsky I guess they do the scaling on-the-fly so users have to wait for it to load.

Comment: You should be resizing the images and storing the end result to serve to your users. Do not do resizing on the fly